# ¿Cómo obtener los datos en Laravel Eloquent ORM de una relación de dos tablas?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola amigos desarrolladores, estoy trabajando con **Laravel 5.8** y deseo que se muestre todos los datos de ambas tablas en una consulta en **Eloquent ORM**. Este es mi código de los modelos y el controlador. Es una relación de **UNO a MUCHOS** entre *Departamentos* y *Categoría*.

***Modelo Departamentos:***

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Departamento extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'departamentos'; /* Nombre de Tabla */
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id'; /* Llave Primaria */
    public $incrementing = false; /* ID Incremento */

    /* Campos */
    protected $fillable = [
        'Departamento', 'Descripcion'
    ];

    public function categoria(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Categoria', 'dep_Id', 'Id');
    }
}
```

***Modelo Categoria:***

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categoria extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'categorias'; /* Nombre de Tabla */
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id'; /* Llave Primaria */
    public $incrementing = false; /* ID Incremento */

    /* Campos */
    protected $fillable = [
        'dep_Id', 'Categoria', 'Descripcion', 
    ];

    /**/
    public function departamento(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Departamento', 'dep_Id', 'Id');
    }
}
```

***Controlador:***

Y este es el Controlador. Deseo mostrarlo en formato JSON para consumirlo posteriormente. Deseo mostrar los registros de ambas tablas mediante un `$id` en el método `show`.

```
public function show($id)
    {

        $Departamento = Departamento::find($id);
        $ListaDepartamento = array('Departamento' => $Departamento);
        $Categoria = Categoria::find($id);
        $cat1 = array('Categoria' => $Categoria);
        $Datoss =  $Categoria;

        return response()->json($Datoss); // JSON
    }
```

Me gustaría que me echaran una mano ya que de tantos intentos no me sale como esperaba. Que no sea por Query Builder, sino por Eloquent ORM para simplificar más el código. Gracias.

Comment: Te podemos auxiliar pero no termino de entender la consulta que deseas lograr así como tampoco el resultado deseado

Comment: Deseo extraer por medio de JSON una consulta de dos tablas. Qué los datos de Departamentos y Categoria me aparezcan en una sola consulta en JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes devolver un array con los elementos que necesitas

```
return response()->json([
     'Departamento' => Departamento::find($id),
     'Categoria' => Categoria::find($id)
]);
```

Comment: Me gusto la respuesta, tan simple como eso.. gracias... ya lo implemente en mi controlador...